# silverlight pivotviewer control does not display tiles

Tags: silverlight, pivot

I have a silverlight pivotviewer control which is correctly loading the .cxml file and then requesting the appropriate .dzc file and the facets are populated and I can see how many items I have as well as search them, but no tiles are displayed in the main view area.  I looked at the output and saw these binding errors:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'ViewportPadding' property not found on 'Microsoft.Pivot.Internal.ViewModels.CollectionViewerViewModel' 'Microsoft.Pivot.Internal.ViewModels.CollectionViewerViewModel' (HashCode=65819928). BindingExpression: Path='ViewportPadding' DataItem='Microsoft.Pivot.Internal.ViewModels.CollectionViewerViewModel' (HashCode=65819928); target element is 'Microsoft.Pivot.Internal.Controls.SeahorseItemExitHost' (Name='PART_ExitHost'); target property is 'Margin' (type 'System.Windows.Thickness')..
System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'LayoutEngine' property not found on 'Microsoft.Pivot.Internal.ViewModels.CollectionViewerViewModel' 'Microsoft.Pivot.Internal.ViewModels.CollectionViewerViewModel' (HashCode=65819928). BindingExpression: Path='LayoutEngine' DataItem='Microsoft.Pivot.Internal.ViewModels.CollectionViewerViewModel' (HashCode=65819928); target element is 'Microsoft.Pivot.Internal.Controls.SeahorseItemExitHost' (Name='PART_ExitHost'); target property is 'LayoutEngine' (type 'Microsoft.Pivot.Internal.ItemLayouts.ILayoutEngine')..
System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'PositionInWindow' property not found on 'Microsoft.Pivot.Internal.ViewModels.CollectionViewerViewModel' 'Microsoft.Pivot.Internal.ViewModels.CollectionViewerViewModel' (HashCode=65819928). BindingExpression: Path='PositionInWindow' DataItem='Microsoft.Pivot.Internal.ViewModels.CollectionViewerViewModel' (HashCode=65819928); target element is 'Microsoft.Pivot.Internal.Controls.SeahorseItemExitHost' (Name='PART_ExitHost'); target property is 'PositionInWindow' (type 'System.Windows.Point')..
```

"LayoutEngine" seems like it would be related but I have no idea why the supplied control would have binding issues.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem as I set min. constraints for the pivotviewer inside a scroll viewer but the dimensions were still auto and it was inside a scroll viewer:

http://betaforums.silverlight.net/forums/p/211146/497407.aspx

Once I set max constraints and placed it in a grid, all the tiles started showing up.

Comment: Unbelievable...I have been looking at HttpHandlers as the PivotViewer was not asking for Images via my HttpHandler via my HttpHandler for JPG's. Setting the Height and Width has caused the Images to be requested...BTW that link does not work.